# How to have more than one dropdown in Materialize CSS?

Tags: opencart, materialize

I'm currently working in OpenCart 3 and using Materialize 0.99.0.
But I've run into an issue with the dropdowns on my main menu. I need to have more than one dropdown in it but the catch is that it's all being generated. Looking at the code for dropdowns on Materialize it goes like this:

```
  <!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
  <a class='dropdown-button btn' href='#' data-activates='dropdown1'>Drop Me!</a>

  <!-- Dropdown Structure -->
  <ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content'>
    <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">view_module</i>four</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">cloud</i>five</a></li>
  </ul>
```

If I put this in my OpenCart template it uses the 'Dropdown1' ID for every dropdown which of course will not work. How do I solve this?

The code in OpenCart goes like this:

```
{% if categories %}
    {% for category in categories %}
        {% if category.children %}
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-button" data-activates="dropdown1">{{ category.name }}<i class="mdi mdi-menu-down"></i></a>
                {% for children in category.children|batch(category.children|length / category.column|round(1, 'ceil')) %}
                    <ul id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
                        {% for child in children %}
                            <li><a href="{{ child.href }}">{{ child.name }}</a></li>
                        {% endfor %}
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="{{ category.href }}" class="see-all">{{ text_all }} {{ category.name }}</a></li>
                    </ul>
                {% endfor %}
            </li>
        {% else %}
            <li><a href="{{ category.href }}">{{ category.name }}</a></li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

So basically what I need is that either Materialize can be converted to not use ID's but something else that doesn't have to be unique but still works or I need a function that generates a unique ID for every loop and puts the ID there.

I really need your help with this and I can't believe I can't find anything about it on the internet. How can I be the only one running into this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it along with help from a good friend on Twitch.
What we did is we set an 'I' value and let that increment for every loop and then print that out accordingly in the 'Data Activates' and 'ID'.

The code for the menu.twig goes as follows now:

```
{% if categories %}
{% for category in categories %}
    {% if category.children %}
        <li>
            {% set i = i + 1 %}
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-button" data-activates="{{ i }}">{{ category.name }}<i class="mdi mdi-menu-down"></i></a>
            {% for children in category.children|batch(category.children|length / category.column|round(1, 'ceil')) %}
                <ul id="{{ i }}" class="dropdown-content">
                    {% for child in children %}
                        <li><a href="{{ child.href }}">{{ child.name }}</a></li>
                    {% endfor %}
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="{{ category.href }}" class="see-all">{{ text_all }} {{ category.name }}</a></li>
                </ul>

            {% endfor %}
        </li>
    {% else %}
        <li><a href="{{ category.href }}">{{ category.name }}</a></li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```